# How can IPv6 host know default router's IPv6 address using RA?

Tags: ip, ipv6, ip-address, network-discovery, icmpv6

I know an IPv6 host will send Router Solicitation (RS) messages, and a router on the link will reply Router Advertisement (RA) messages.

In the RA message, there is the `Source Link-Layer Address` and `Prefix Information` in options. So a host can know the router's MAC address, and it can generate it's IPv6 address.

How can a host know the router's IPv6 address (router's link-local or global address)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RA IPv6 packet will have the router address as the source IPv6 address.

A host doesn't really need to know the router's IP address to send packets to other hosts. On a LAN, frames are sent to a layer-2 (MAC) address. The layer-3 IPv6 packet will have the destination host IPv6 address, not the router address. If a host is on a different LAN, the packet will still have the destination host IPv6 address, but the frame will have the destination MAC address of the router.